# Kosher Coconut Oil Packed in Non-Kosher facility

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher

If the Coconut Oil is Kosher but is packed in non-Kosher facility, is it still kosher?

Comment: Hi Liat and welcome to mi.yodeya! You might get more precise answers if you specify more about the product you are referring to, since there could be many things about a facility that render it "non-kosher", affecting the status of the oil produced there.

Comment: Primarily opinion based?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's a vague question (what means "packed") but should be OK.

Comment: @Shmuel So unclear what you are asking? There is no good answer here.

Comment: @DoubleAA that yes.

Comment: Good catch @Menachem. I'm closing it as a duplicate. Liat, if that other question doesn't help you, please [edit] this one to clarify what you mean to ask.